# Determine which TLS version was negotiated by client to a Netty server, with SniHandler

Tags: netty, netty4

I am current working on a Netty server with SniHandler in the pipeline. I would like to log the negotiated TLS version in session, but I cannot find this information in SniHandler or SniHandler.SslContext.

I was trying to access the SslHandler from SniHandler, but I didn't figure out how since the SniHandler is initiated as below:

```
p.addLast("sniHandler", new SniHandler(options.domainNameMapping));
```

I don't know if I am on the right track. Hope someone could give me some advices on retrieving TLS version form session.

Thanks

I am sorry to ask a similar question which should be solved a month ago.
[Determine which TLS version was negotiated by client to a netty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68184246/determine-which-tls-version-was-negotiated-by-client-to-a-netty-server)

Also, that is a minor side of question I would like to know.
I was trying to get the sniHandler described above from ctx in another handler, with code below.

```
SniHandler sniHandler = (SniHandler) ctx.pipeline().get("sniHandler");
```

It seems to return a null value to me, has anyone know what am I missing?

ThanksThanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SniHandler` is replaced with an `SslHandler` once the SNI informations are parsed. So you would get the informations from the `SslHandler`.

Something like:

```
SslHandler sslHandler = ctx.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class);
SSLEngine engine = sslHandler.engine();
String protocol = engine.getSession().getProtocol();
```